# MySQL When Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a trigger using MySQL but I am running into an error.The constraint being: A user may not bid on an item he or she is also selling.

```
Create Trigger before_insert_bid
Before Insert on Bid
for each row
when exists(
             Select *
             From Item
             Where Item.UserID = new.UserID
             AND Item.ItemID = new.ItemID
)
begin
     Call 'You cannot bid on your own item';
end;
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out what the error is, and how I would fix it, I have been trying to debug this for the past hour, am I using the when clause incorrectly or do I have to use something else?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use an `if` inside the body.

Comment: How exactly? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Try `if exists (...`

Comment: This is what I did:

Create Trigger before_insert_bid
After Insert on Bid
for each row
begin
if Item.UserID = new.UserID
             AND Item.ItemID = new.ItemID
then call 'Error';
end if;
end;

But it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, the trigger would look like this:

```
delimiter $$

create Trigger before_insert_bid before Insert on Bid for each row
begin
    if (exists (Select 1 from Item i Where i.UserID = new.UserID and i.ItemID = new.ItemID))
    then
         signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'You cannot bid on your own item';
    end if;
end;$$

delimiter ;
```

Since MySQL 5.5, `signal` is the preferred method of returning an error from a trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but we cant use signal because our school's mysql isnt upto date

Comment: If i wanted to add another constraint for the same trigger, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: @vampyfreak . . . You add another `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
...
for each row
IF EXISTS(   
         Select *
         From Item
         Where Item.UserID = new.UserID
         AND Item.ItemID = new.ItemID
) then
   begin
       Call `You cannot bid on your own item`;
   end;
end if;
```

Comment: I did try something like that, but its throwing an error on the call statement, saying that the syntax isnt correct, do you know why by any chance?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Error1: You cannot bid on your own item'' at line 11

Comment: Do you use `'` quote in call statement ?

Comment: Yeah I did use that. Was I not supposed to?

Call 'Error1: You cannot bid on your own item';

Comment: @vampyfreak -  Try quotes, what is in my answer for `call` statement. note, that they are not `'`

Comment: What is mysql version ?

Comment: the version is 5.1.73

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that version, for my `5.7` version  this works